# double or float type data rounds off automatically

Tags: c++, rounding

I was trying to find maximum and minimum of given numbers with this code

```
    double a[50], max, min; long int k,i,j,n;
    cout<<"How many numbers you want to examine with";
    cin>>n;
    cout<<"type the numbers you want to know maximum and minimum of";
    i = 0;
    while (i<n)
    {
      cin>>a[i];
      i++; 
    }

    max = a[0];
    for (j=0; j<n; j++){
        if (a[j] >= max) {
            max = a[j];
        }

    }
    cout<<"Maximum of given numbers is "<<max <<"\n";
    min = a[0];
    for (k=0; k<n; k++){
        if (a[k]<=min){
            min = a[k];
        }
    }
    cout<<"Minimum of given numbers is "<< min;
```

Then I gave input values as `n = 3` & three values to be `34543.54`, `-6.543467`, `0`.
But I got answers which are rounded off like this

```
Maximum of given numbers is 34543.5
Minimum of given numbers is -6.54347
```

I didn't use and round off functions, also I'm using double for array, max and min then why am I getting rounding off values. Is there any way to avoid it?

Comment: You are confusing the value of a number, and what digits printing the value displays on the screen. They are not the same.

Comment: Do some debugging. Is the value being rounded by your calculations, or is it being calculated to full precision and the rounding is happening during the printing?

Comment: @gnasher729 A number is identified by the style of digits it's been written. What do you mean by value of a number. Number is itself a value. Can you please explain what did you mean? what am I confusing?

Comment: @RaymondChen I'm using relational operators to get minimum and maximum value. No calculations is going on. And yeah it has been rounded off during the printing. How can I add precision in cout? or make  my code display right?

Comment: Okay, so you determined that the value is correct and the problem is with the printing. So the real question is not "why is the value being rounded" (because you observed that it has full precision) but rather "how do I print more digits?"

Comment: @RaymondChen No, the question is still "why is the value being rounded?" because as you can see the maximum number is `34543.54` but on output screen it shows `34543.5` which is the round off of the number. So does the same with minimum number as it is also rounded off to `-6.54347` from the original number `-6.543467`. My question is still why it has been rounded off despite of no use and round function. So is it already in C++ by default to round off the value as result?

Comment: @Saurabh the value isn't rounded off. C++ prints 6 digits of precision by default so 34543.54 and -6.543467 will be printed out as 34543.5 and -6.54347. Print more digits and you'll see the actual values being stored

Comment: @phuclv Okay, so it means that if I put any float number then it only shows 6 digits precision on output. Is it right? Is there any way to improve the precision using some function or library?

Comment: @Saurabh yes, the [default *printing* precision](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/precision) [set by `std::basic_ios<CharT,Traits>::init` is 6](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/init) so regardless of the value it'll always print maximum 6 digits. And if you use IEEE-754 double the *type* precision is always 53 bits. For higher precision (like 128-bit) or arbitrary precision use some libraries like [Boost.Multiprecision](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/index.html) or [MPFR](https://www.mpfr.org/)